# One way ticket to India

Tags: us-citizens, india

My son is a US citizen and is travelling to India from USA on a one way ticket. He has a valid visa(entry visa, type X). Please let me know if anybody sees any concerns with this journey with respect to boarding a direct flight and entry into India. Also, if there is anything to keep in mind while performing this journey. Thank you.

Comment: Timatic doesn't note a requirement that I can see to have return travel booked for entry to India even for Americans traveling on tourist visa. I can't imagine they would complain about that for someone in possession of a long-stay visa.

Comment: Be aware that one-way flights are sometimes _very_ expensive - I have seen many cases where they cost _more_ than a round trip ticket. That doesn't hinder you in any way; you might just lose some money.

Comment: I emailed the airline and this is the response I got:

_U.S. citizens traveling to India must have a Valid U.S. passport and may
travel one way as long as the visa is not tourist or business._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We travelled like this on a one way ticket and the only thing that was checked by the airline was the visa and the one way ticket. Since, it was not a business or a tourist visa, the airline allowed us to board the flight. Further, at immigration in India, no questions were asked.